# Loaded nodes (id, node-name) then edges (source, target, weight), No graph in overview?

Tags: directed-graph, gephi

I'm new to Gephi but understand graphs, graph math, and social graph analytics very well, especially influence metrics).

I have a directed-graph data coded up as sequences of topics in Aesop's fables, generated by a proprietary automated topic generation algorithm.

The topics are text (nodes) and I sorted the list alphabetically to assigned a node ID (id) to each topic (node).

Then I built the edges file; source, target, weight (ratio of the two weights... call it a topical_valence_index)

I loaded in the nodes as a node-graph, then the edges as an edge-graph.

I've attached screen captures of both.

When I click Overview, no graph appears!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something seems to be wrong with your edges. I see source `faith/belief - null` where I would expect the corresponding node ID for `faith/belief`. The presence of `null` after `faith/belief` indicates that Gephi tries to recover the id of the node and finds `null` instead